# How can I extract information on an assignment further up the call stack?

Tags: r, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, callstack

for behind the scences processes in a larger R Shiny app, I want to recover the name to which the user assigns.

For example, if a user binds the value 1 to the name x (`x <- 1`), then I want to extract the name "x" from the call stack. Following some research on function evaluation and call stack environments in R ([here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#call-stack), [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html#ast-funs), [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/), and ?sys.parent), I have been able to put together a partial solution. It returns a call class object viable for manipulation using the rlang package.

```r
f <- function() sys.call(which = 1)
(assign("x", f()))
```

Notwithstanding, both the assignment operator `x <- 1` (returns f()) and its prefix form `` `<-`("x", 1) `` (returns 1) break my solution. I find that puzzling because all three functions(`<-`, `` `<-`() ``, and `assign()`) have similar abstract syntax trees. Anyhow, users of my code should follow routine assigment patterns and not notice anything at all.

Hints or pointers to further resources are much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I believe I have found an answer. The assignment operator `<-` is a primitive function. It ships precompiled in C.  The function `assign()`, in contrast, is not primitive. Apparently, primitive functions do not pass through the same call stack. To give another example:

```r
is.primitive(`+`) # TRUE
add <- function() {
  print(sys.calls())
  1
}
is.primitive(add) # FALSE
(1 + add()) # `+` doesn't show
```

The output leads me to believe that the sys.*** family of functions reads the call stack of R's interpreter. Calls that don't need interpretation don't go through there. Can anyone confirm?